# How to allow right to left languages in Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, hebrew, right-to-left

I am interested in creating a website in Hebrew using Ruby on Rails 3. The problem is when I put Hebrew into my view I am told that it is not supported and I should add UTF-8.

I've been working on this for a while and I Can't seem to find how to do this. I am also using Sqlite3 and I would like to save Hebrew strings there too.

How would I achieve this?

The error code I am given is:

`Your template was not saved as valid UTF-8. Please either specify UTF-8 as the encoding for your template in your text editor, or mark the template with its encoding by inserting the following as the first line of the template:...`

**Edit:**

Problem was I was working on Notepad++ which did not save my files in UTF-8 format although they  were UTF-8 formated files. Solved by changing file format.

Comment: Please add specific code and error messages/stacktraces.

Comment: The "code" is simply adding a hebrew word into the view. I added the error code to the view.

Comment: This sounds like a file encoding problem. What editor are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using notepad++, first set the encoding to "Encode in UTF-8" and then start coding. If you have already created/saved the file then just changing the encoding type will not do. You will have to keep a copy of the existing code, then delete the existing file, open notepad++, set the encoding first(Encode in UTF-8) and then start writing/copying the code to it. This way utf-8 encoding is ensured and you won't have to put "# encoding: UTF-8" at the top of your file.

Answer (score 2):

You should try adding on the first line of your `.rb` files the following:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

and on the first line of your `.erb`

```
<%# encoding: utf-8 %>
```

`encoding: utf-8` and `coding: utf-8` and are equivalent.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This won't work on its own unless the file is properly encoded. Apparently Notepad++ has issues with unicode on anything later than Windows XP: http://superuser.com/questions/21135/how-can-i-edit-unicode-text-in-notepad

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that in your database configurations utf-8 is the default character set, and not latin1.
If you use MySQL change it in the "MySQL Server Instance Config Wizard".

EDIT: Try putting this code in your application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
before_filter :set_charset

def set_charset
@headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=utf-8"
end
end
```

read more on this article: http://www.dotmana.com/?p=95

Comment: What about enabling on the view side?

Comment: I get a message saying that `You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!` I think it doesn't recognize headers

Comment: Try `response.headers["Content-Type"] = 'text/html; charset=utf-8'`

Comment: It now recognizes headers, but still I get an error when I add hebrew to the view

Answer (score 1):

you can put

```
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

in your `config/application.rb` which is equivalent to

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

which in turn is the equivalent to putting:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

or a BOM at the top of every file.

This allows utf-8 globally on all files of the rails app. 
If you want a global option on all ruby files, you can use the `-Ku` ruby option and set it via the `RUBYOPT` environment variable, like:

```
export RUBYOPT=-Ku
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by the file encoding itself. Make sure you have set UTF-8 as default encoding for project in your editor/IDE preferences.

Edit:

You can check file for encoding with:

```
file -I myview.erb.html
```

(that's a capital 'i').

Comment: I got voted down but I still encourage you to double check that your file is properly encoded in UTF8. I still think this might be it.

Comment: So notepad++ might be the issue - seems to have issues with the encoding? Surelt Kamil should be reward the correct answer?