# Rails character problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have problems when rewriting the Danish letters in view files as Æ Ø Å and I get this error in view: Your template was not saved as valid UTF-8. I have changed the configuration file to Danish, but I still get the error.

I have seen that all of the rails files are saved as ANSI. Do I need to change all the files to UTF-8 or are there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866977/how-to-allow-right-to-left-languages-in-ruby-on-rails-3) may be related to yours.

Your view files' encoding may be broken.
For example, there could somehow be an [UTF-8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) left at the beginning, but the remaining file is encoded in ANSI.

- Try converting it explicitly.
- if this doesn't help try another editor and saving it there.
- Check the file contents with a hex editor to make sure no BOM is present.

Btw, if you have to convert all files from the project, you can try using a utility like [iconv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv).

Comment: Then I should format all of my view files from ANSI to UTF-8.