# Why does Rails 3 pitch a fit about UTF-8 character encoding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8

I just started work on a new Rails app, using the bright and shiny new version of Rails, 3.2.1. Previously, I had only used up to version 3.0.9. Before I describe my error, let it be known that I am using Ruby version `ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]` on Windows 7 32-bit. I have not changed my version of Ruby recently. I am using Notepad++ v5.9.3 and haven't (on purpose) changed any default settings.

When I ran my new app for the first time, I got an odd message:

```
ActionView::WrongEncodingError in Index#index

Your template was not saved as valid UTF-8. Please either specify UTF-8 as the encoding for your template in your text editor, or mark the template with its encoding by inserting the following as the first line of the template:

# encoding: <name of correct encoding>.
```

I do not understand why I am getting this error all of a sudden. Is it part of changes made to Rails 3.2.1? It is easily fixed by going into Notepad++ and using the Encoding menu option "Convert to UTF-8" but, like I said, I've never had to do this before.

The other odd thing is that even the files that Rails generates are generated with ANSI encoding when I use a generator. Overall, I'm confused and I want to make sure that I'm using good programming practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it part of changes made to Rails 3.2.1? It is easily fixed by going into Notepad++ and using the Encoding menu option "Convert to UTF-8" but, like I said, I've never had to do this before.

Yes. Rails 3.0+ (I think) requires all templates to be saved in UTF-8 encoding. You need to save the file as UTF-8. If that still doesn't work, set the encoding explicitly by adding on the first line of your `.rb` files the following:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

Add this to the first line of your `.erb` templates:

```
<%# encoding: utf-8 %>
```

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866977/how-to-allow-right-to-left-languages-in-ruby-on-rails-3), and [this similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124120/rails-character-problem). Sounds to me like your editor's encoding settings changed since you originally created the files.

> The other odd thing is that even the files that Rails generates are generated with ANSI encoding when I use a generator. Overall, I'm confused and I want to make sure that I'm using good programming practices.

That is quite odd, and I'm not sure I have a good suggestion for that one, other then trying to add `Encoding.default_external = "UTF-8"` to your `config.ru` and `config/environment.rb` files.

Answer (score -1):

I had tried the `encoding: utf-8` method without luck, but I resolved the issue when I changed the encoding using **Notepad++**.  Thanks!