# What is the best way to handle submission of non-utf-8 data in Rails 3 forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, utf-8

I am using Rails 3.2.3 and Ruby 1.9.3.
I have a model called called Post that accepts a title and a description.
The front-end of the site receives information submitted through the back-end through an ajax request. When I fill out the form with, let's say

```
title: foo
content: foobar
```

and submit it, I am able to view data through the front-end without a problem.

However, whenever I submit non-utf8 data through the form, for example (mind the fancy quotes):

```
title: foo
content: “foobar”
```

When I try to render the form I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with ASCII-8BIT string))
```

My .js.erb file looks like this:

```
$("#my_post").html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'post') %>');
```

I realize this is an issue with encoding, but I'm not sure how I should handle it the best way. I thought of several options:

1. Strip out non-utf8 by using the iconv library -- do this via a before_save filter for every single model in my application
2. [Specifying at the top of the js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428027/why-does-rails-3-pitch-a-fit-about-utf-8-character-encoding) that the document contains utf-8 (not sure this would work)
3. Using `accept-charset="UTF-8"` in my form to force the browser to avoid submission of non-utf-8 content.

I'm not even sure these solutions would help and the most efficient way to do this would be.
Thanks!

Comment: The `form_tag` view helper will add `accept-charset="UTF-8"` for you.  Any reason you can't use `form_tag`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look carefully to see if

- You're actually sending non-UTF-8 data to your app, or
- You're sending UTF-8 data, but it is not being recognized by Ruby/Rails

To see which it is, you need to examine the data on the "wire." (What's being sent on the Internet.) Use a peeking tool such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or a proxy spy such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Curly quotes can be sent using 8859 or UTF-8.

**Recommendation** You should set the HTML page to be UTF-8. Any Ajax sent from scripts on the page should then also use UTF-8. See http://www.utf8.com/

**Added** (Re: comment about how Rails sets form's character encoding)

The issue for Ajax character encoding is how was the **page's** encoding set. [A blog post.](http://www.kanthak.net/explorations/blog/rails/ajax_and_charsets.html) So be sure to set the page's UTF-8 encoding in your page template.

Comment: Rails sets the charset to UTF-8 by default.

Comment: @GabeKopley -- That's only setting the encoding for the form. It has no effect on Ajax calls.

Comment: The linked blog post author is wanting his page in the ISO-8859-15 charset.  You don't need to do this for UTF-8, it's the Rails default.

Comment: How to let users post an arbitrary encoding and the Rails server detects and convert it to UTF-8? My standard form has accept-charset but the browser never converts the uploaded files (non UTF-8) to UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're not using the form helpers because you mention the question of adding `accept-charset="UTF-8"` to your form.

The form helpers will add the `accept-charset` attribute as well as the [snowman parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3348524/283398) which together should ensure you get UTF-8 data from the browser.

See the [Rails Form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) guide.